# Set comboBox to custom display format

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, properties

I've got a WinForms comboBox that contains a list of "Regions" (a custom class I've set up). Each `Region` has properties `Name`, `Abbreviation`, etc. I know I can set the comboBox to `comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";`, but I want the display formatting to be `"(" + Abbreviation + ") " + Name` (e.g. `(OR) Oregon`).

I know I could create a separate property for this (e.g. `DisplayName`) and just set the `comboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";` but is there another way to do it? Something like `comboBox.DisplayMember = "(" + Abbreviation + ") " + Name;` or whatever?

Comment: As far as I know no, there is no better way. Overriding ToString is similar but you have to write code as well in the class, so using a custom made property makes sense

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use combobox's Format event.

```
 private void comboBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = ((yourClass)e.ListItem).Property1;
        string LastName = ((yourClass)e.ListItem).Property2;
        e.Value = Name + " " + LastName;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Just for reference, the *preferred* way to do it would be to make a "DisplayName" property, do all the "formatting logic" in the `get` for that property, then just use `comboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";`, correct?

Comment: @derekantrican Yes, the prefered way is that.

Comment: @derekantrican: I filled up a combobox with DateTime values I want to display as "MMM yyyy". Th only way to use a `DisplayName` or to overrride `ToString()` would be to create a special display object. Therefore this `Format` event approach is very handy.

Answer (score 9):

This is quite old, but I struggled to find why the `Format` event was not fired.

You also need to set `ComboBox.FormattingEnabled` to `true` in order to get the event invoked and used.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to modify the ´ToString()´ method of your class.

If you do that you will change the way the class is isualized everywhere (Comboboxes, listboxes, etc)

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return "(" + Abbreviation + ") " + Name;
}
```

It's useless if you want a diferent visualitzation for diferent places, but perfect if you want it always to be the same