# C# combobox set custom DiplayMember

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm binding combobox to a DataTable (table columns are "NAME", "SURNAME" and "ID"). Currently I have set ValueMember to "ID", and DisplayMember to "SURNAME". I wish to change DisplayMember - and DisplayMember only. By reading all sorts of documentation (including this forum) It can be achieved by exposing a custom property and bind combobox to that, however I'm having difficulties with It.

Closest solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192443/set-combobox-to-custom-display-format) where you can format combobox, but that changes ValueMember too. Though under accepted answer is mentioned that you can do same with only DisplayMember by exposing a property...

So I tried with this:

```
  private string _employee;
  public string MyDisplay
        {
            get
            {
                DataRowView r = (DataRowView)this.SelectedItem;
                DataRow s = r.Row;
                return _employee= s["SURNAME"].ToString() + " " + s["NAME"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this._employee = value;
            }
        }
```

But that doesn't display my custom DisplayMember when I bind It to **MyDisplay**, when I scroll combobox Items It's Text is only **System.Data.DataRowView**.

What is the correct way to accomplish this ?

EDIT:

My full code for binding comboboxes:

```
 private void FillCombobox()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
                {
                       using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MYSCHEMA.EMPLOYEES"))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("CHOOSE_SELECT_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 6, ParameterDirection.Input));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("RESULT_OUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                        using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter())
                        {
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }

                    //bind combobox
                    BindData(dt, Combobox1, "MyDisplay", "ID");
              }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }

        private void BindData(DataTable dt, ComboBox ctl, string displayMember, string valueMember)
        {
            if (ctl.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ctl.Invoke(new Action<DataTable, ComboBox, string, string>(BindData),
                               dt,
                               ctl,
                               displayMember,
                               valueMember);
            }
            else
            {
                ctl.DisplayMember = displayMember;
                ctl.ValueMember = valueMember;
                ctl.DataSource = dt;
                ctl.Text = "";
                ctl.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please paste your full code. Including where you do the data binding

Comment: `DisplayMember` is supposed to be a property _of the selected object_. I'm not even sure it'd work with a DataRow. I suggest filling up your ComboBox with custom objects.

Comment: @NicoRiff, see my edited question, I bind comboboxes like that. binding goes in line **BindData(dt, Combobox1, "MyDisplay", "ID");**

Comment: @Lucy82 It seems it s is getting you a lot of effort to do the data binding... are you working on separate threads with the UI or are you creating the combobox dinamically??

Comment: @NicoRiff, there is plenty of comboboxes in same form, so I do It like this to filll them all at same time (and fast), instead of e.g. placing code in each Enter event of combobox

Comment: @Nyerguds, how to do that when I have a Datatable?

Comment: @NicoRiff, yes I'm working on separate thread to fiil comboboxes, to avoid any form_load issues while doing It. Comboboxes (about 15 of them, each one with different stored procedure) get's filled in less than 0.4 sec, so It's super fast this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is one simple, one line mehod to do that, no property of any kind required. Just a simple add of calculated column to a Datatable in a place where you bind Combobox, and then you just set that column as DiplayMember. So my solution to all problem follows as this:

```
   //Add calculated column to Datatable and set this column to DiplayMember
   dt.Columns.Add("MyDisplay", typeof(string),"SURNAME + " " + NAME");
```

So, It's an easy one. I even included settings for display in .config, so I can change combobox DisplayMember to whatever I like. Neat solution :)